# Why are Python exe files so large?

Tags: python, compilation, exe

I converted an empty Python file to an exe file with the pyinstaller library, and the exe file size was 6.694 MB.
Why was the size of the exe file so large even though the Python file was empty and there was no reference to it?
really why?

Comment: If I understood that correctly earlier, it's packing all the libraries in your environment.

Comment: Why does it have to do this before I import those modules?

Comment: This is my final output file.

Comment: I didn't really understood why and wasn't digging deeper. I just learned that if I want the smallest exe file possible, I need new env and I should be good to go. But I think there is gonna be an answer on the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the answer to my questions myself.
In many languages, such as C#, the script file is initially completely empty.
In C#, for example, to print text on a console, you must first use the system library, the Console class, WriteLine method, and then do so.
While in each Python file you have access to a number of default classes and functions. Including the print function that you can use to easily print text.
The size of this raw data in Python files is not small at all.
In fact, before the first line of each Python file, there is a line that import the Python default library.
I wish Python was completely empty at first.